# Maven site deploy authentication error with scp

Tags: maven-2

I get Auth fail error when running `mvn -X site:deploy`.

```
org.apache.maven.wagon.authentication.AuthenticationException: Cannot connect. Reason: Auth fail
```

It seems that the correct private key is used and I can scp files normally to the project site directory using scp on Ubuntu.

What can be causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that I forgot to specify the passphrase for my private key.